# self-signed certificates in an identity federation scenario

Tags: x509certificate, wif, ca

I'm using WCF webservices with WIF. More specification, I'm using WS2007FederationHttpBinding. All works well on the localhost machine used for development.

However, when trying a remote install with the server deployed on IIS and the client being launched from an other PC, my channel Open method fails with the following exception :

> The X.509 certificate CN=MyOwnCertificate chain building failed. The certificate that was used has a trust chain that cannot be verified. Replace the certificate or change the certificateValidationMode.

(MyOwnCertificate being a self-signed certificate using makecert; the certificate has been inserted in Trusted Root Certification Authorities).

So I first tried to remove this constraint by the following code, for test purposes :

```
this.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.PeerOrChainTrust; 
        this.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
```

which indeeds removes the initial exception fault. However the InnerSecurityTokenProvider now returns its own exception :

> "Le message n'a pas pu être traité car l'action
>   'http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/RST/SCT' n'est pas
>   valide ou non reconnue."}

(sorry for the french message).

Is there a way to make self-signed certificates work in such a remote scenario ? (which I would prefer since I only need the certificate for internal use)

Would it work with a certificate generated with openssl (http://www.freebsdmadeeasy.com/tutorials/freebsd/create-a-ca-with-openssl.php) ?

Your help will be most welcome. Thanks.

EDIT 06/01/2012 : Also tested with a signed certificate as suggested (+ revocation list), works in local but fails in remote. Certs have been defined as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733813.aspx). I have the CA certificate deployed under Trusted Root. The IP and Server certificates are deployed in MY (with pfx) and Trusted People (with cer). Also IIS has been setup so that the NETWORK account can access private keys deployed under LOCALMACHINE MY.

EDIT 07/01/2012 : It works when the certificate is issued by an official CA (i.e verisign, thawte ...)

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a certificate called, say, "SelfCA"; then inserting that into your Trusted root store. Then create a new certificate for your use, but this time sign it with "SelfCA".

Refer to this page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733813.aspx

Comment: @fabien, I'm not sure what you are refering to.

Comment: The signing of certificates works as you suggested. However, in a client-server architecture, my client still gets an error, probably due to the fact that it has no idea who my CA is. I tested by inserting the CA on the client machine, but still doesn't work. I'm now testing with certificates from CA vendors, maybe that will solve the issue.